# Чтение .png с помощью Lua

Tags: c++, lua, bitmap, png

Доброе время суток.
Необходимо сделать скрипт на Lua который будет читать png файлы, записывая каждый пиксель в массив, затем по вызову передавать этот массив в С++ для дальнейшей обработки. Перепробовал много библиотек, некоторые требуют LuaJit или iTorch(а именно ffi модуль) и тд. Мне же нужна простенькая библиотека или функция которая будет выполнять эту задачу, интересуюсь как это реализовать и будет ли от этого какой-либо профит? Часто вижу что скрипты это быстро и тд но в данном случае будет выгода по времени загрузки или лучше писать класс на с++ и пускать в отдельный поток?

Comment: Лучше писать сразу на С++. Скрипты это не быстро.

Comment: Вот чем тебе не нравиться boost png io ?

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/gil/doc/html/g_i_l_0169.html

По сути ты запускаешь из C++ интерпретатор скриптов написанный на C.. )))

Не соглашусь с пред. коментарием lua очень быстрый скриптовый язык!

Comment: *скрипты это быстро* - "быстро" в этом контексте явно относится не к скорости работы

Comment: как-то сталкивался с подобной задачей - имелось приложение написанное на `c++` которое обрабатывало изображения на основе конфигурационных файлов, при этом конфигурационные файлы часто менялись а обрабатываемые изображения могли быть не просто прочитаны из файла, а слеплены из нескольких изображений. В такой ситуации я по быстому набросал модуль для `lua` на базе `opencv` который читал изображение + позволял его минимально обрабатывать (копирование, resize). В вашем случае советую сделать подобным образом, если, конечно, вам не обойтись без использования `lua`